# Show a polar function's diffrentiability

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polar-coordinates

I need to show that $f(r,\theta)=r\sin(2\theta)\ r>0$ is differentiable at each point in its domain, and also decide whether it's $C^1$ or not. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=\sin(2\theta)$ is continuous and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}=2r\cos(2\theta)$ which is continuous too. Then $f\in\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R^*_+\times [0,\pi[)$ and so $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Would you kindly explain a little further what the domain attached to C1 means?

Comment: your function is simply the function $f:]0,\infty [\times [0,\pi[\longrightarrow \mathbb R; (r,\theta)\longmapsto r\sin(2\theta)$. Then I just proved that your function is $\mathcal C^1$ on $]0,\infty [\times [0,\pi[$.